# Why can not I connect css to jsp?

Tags: css, jsp, java-web-start

I have a css file in with such content.

```
a{
    color: #00FF00;
    font-size: 20px;
}

div{
    color: #19FBFF;
}
body {
    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/1400/900");
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

I connect it to all jsp pages in this way

```
<link href = "styles.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" />
```

But as a result, nothing changes on the page. The project's file hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

Comment: it requires relative path

Comment: the code your provided works fine in my project... What is the current url in the browser when you try and visit the jsp page?